# How to set the margin if using viewbinding

Tags: java, android, android-viewbinding

I want to set the margin on the LinearLayout in activity_main.xml, but because I'm using viewbinding, the margin doesn't show any result. Is there a way to have the margins on the LinearLayout set even when using viewbinding?

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

**acivity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/idLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/idText1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click"
        android:layout_margin="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/idButton1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();         
        setContentView(view);

        binding.idText1.setText("This is view binding");
        binding.idButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "binding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You'd have to change the inflation to `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), false);`.

Comment: Hi thanks for help me. R.id.content, what is the ID of constraintLayout?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I don't see a `ConstraintLayout` anywhere in the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant the ID of the LinearLayout

Comment: Maybe you are looking for padding attribute?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. The `<LinearLayout>`'s ID would be `R.id.idLayout`, but that's not really relevant. The line I gave is exactly as you should type it.